# how to kill a hang connection in jvm when you are outside of a jvm (ubuntu box)?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have an application runs in jboss 4.2.2 server with jdk 1.6. The program has bug in it that it doesn't set http connection timeout when it opens its the connection. So when the third party side has issues the connection is hanged forever which makes the thread hangs as well. And soon we are running out of thread. However, due to the release cycle we can't put a fix in immediately. I was wondering there is a way to terminate a network connection from outside the jvm? So the thread can be release back to the thread pool? I potentially has a lot of connection open to the same third party site so it is nice to figure out the problem connection and just kill that one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for a question of my own, I came across what seems to be a great tutorial on how to externally kill a thread.

http://www.rhcedan.com/2010/06/22/killing-a-java-thread/

Answer (score 0):

You can grep the output of [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) and kill the connection using [tcpkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill), and run this using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

However this cannot be more than a very temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This ServerFault Q & A](https://serverfault.com/questions/315640/how-to-kill-a-tcp-connection-using-tcpkill-utility) may be relevant.  It explains that `tcpkill` will only work if there is active traffic on the connection.

(This is because ... apparently ... `tcpkill` works by sending a TCP RESET packet.  In order for this to work it needs to know the correct sequence number, and it can only figure this out by examining other packets for the session.)